# PETG Sticking to Nozzle

Tags: pla, extruder, nozzle, petg, flashforge-creator

For a while now, my AmazonBasics PETG filament has been working like a charm. Now, it is balling up on my nozzle. I've tried slowing it down, re-leveling the bed, etc. I don't want to go through the hassle of replacing my nozzle with a Micro-Swiss all metal 0.4 mm nozzle. I've tried the other extruder which I know works with PLA, but same results. I'm using a Flashforge Creator Pro(2016).

Comment: Please add pictures and more information (by [edit]) when this happens, e.g. on the first layer or after a few layers. If it is a layer adhesion problem, maybe [this question](/q/727) may help you.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that you're having issues now due to the filament absorbing moisture. I had a big problem with it doing that when I had waited for a few months after opening my filament. Dehydrated it using just my heated plate and a foil lined box over the top and it fixed it right up. If that's something you haven't tried yet perhaps that is what is causing you some grief.

Comment: Welcome at 3D Printing.SE Kaleb! You must have had a ventilation hole or something to get rid of the moist air?

Answer (score 2):

PETG does this. PETG is like glue when soft this is why when you level the bed you have to add an additional 0.1 mm distance for PETG. PETG should not be as close as PLA, but futher away. It will stick to the hotend so preferably change the hotend from brass to a nickle plated nozzle (e.g. Micro Swiss, PETG does not stick to that nozzle at all).

Comment: I've printed kilometers of 2.85 mm PETG filament, but never needed an increased first layer height or an extra clearance between nozzle and bed. I guess it is depending on your setup. It may help, but it could be it also works without such measures.

Comment: Nice, I will change my nozzles I have a bunch of them since one year ago waiting to assembly my third printer and the new ones.

Comment: Its the makeup of PETG, it is a stickier thermal plastic and you get better results if you increase the distance, slightly, between the nozzle and bed. Maker Muse and Tom both suggest the same thing in their YouTube videos. When I print with PETG, I never get any stringing at all and it prints just like PLA. I get near perfect prints with zero cleanup or stringing at the end. When I do figures of any kind I use PETG instead of PLA.